Android studio iguana (patch 1) error: gradle project sync failed. basic functionality will not work properly
I have a project that I wrote 2 months ago and I haven't updated the gradle project since 8.1.3.
Today, when I opened it, I encountered the following error:

Failed to sync gradle project. The basic function will not work properly


I tried to update gradle but android studio failed to update it.
I cleaned it and rebuilt it but it didn't work.
I delete the .gradle folder but it doesn't work.
I tried using a proxy and nothing happens.
I tried to see similar questions but everyone had tried to update gradle and it was useless for me.

What should I do? Can anyone help me?

Have you checked out a new project in android studio? Are you sure Android Studio is working properly? I had similar problem, but I realized that the Android Studio software has a problem.
Update android Studio or SDK. It might be helpful.

Yes that's right. Android Studio does not even open a new project. The problem was not with my project. Thank you for your guidance.
